# Java spaghetti code

Tags: java, android

How to know if my code is spaghetti or not?

Is this is spaghetti code?

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                ((Core) getActivity()).emailCore();
                ((Core) getActivity()).messengerSharer();

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        R.string.text_field_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        R.string.text_field_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html_toast)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            } catch (Error e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        R.string.text_field_toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }
        }
    });
```

And how to write clean and good java code?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does).

Comment: It's event for button click in android and it's from old app i made. I just give example to know how to write clean code and make it readable to anyone will mess with my code later

Comment: Please add the explanation into your question, by clicking the [edit](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/111691/edit) link below it.

Comment: No, it is a pasta code. Lol. Anyway - no - a spaghetti code is an incomprehensible code at all. But you can "optimize" it ofcourse (there isn't so much to say with this code).

Answer (score 2):

```
catch (OutOfMemoryError error)
{    
}
catch (Error e)
{
}
```

Errors should never be caught in Java, only exceptions. An error differs from an exception in the sense that an error is the kind of problem that means something went *really* wrong and not just something was faulty handled in your application.

Take another look at the first one you catch: `OutOfMemoryError`. This literally means your app has ran out of memory. By definition, you can't do anything anymore which includes error handling.

Maybe [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) speaks for itself here:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most applications should not try to catch it.

Comment: Depends on the error. A `NoClassDefError` means a class available at compile time is no longer available. A `UnsatisfiedLinkError` means a native library cannot be used (it can't be found, or it's missing a dependency). You can catch both and decide to use a workaround. 
But I agree that catching errors should be done with very much caution. And `OutOfMemoryErrors` should never be caught at all.

Comment: The Android Studio forced me to catch this error

Comment: @DrProgrammer fair enough,, there are some exceptions to it. Though for the purpose of not confusing new devs, I'll leave it in as a golden rule.

Comment: @Stephan: forced? *Error and its subclasses are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.* (from the docs)

Answer (score 0):

> How to know if my code is spaghetti or not?

There are GoF Patterns and OOD-Principles ([SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) is an couple of good working principles) agains "Spaghetti-Code".

> Is this is spaghetti code?

A little bit.

> And how to write clean and good java code?

1. Find OOD-Principles you like to use in parts of your project.
2. Order them by importance
3. Energy Mr. Scott.